# How to change column length of existing table in SQL?

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-migrations

I have one SQL table which will contain (TEXT/VARCHAR) columns of some length.

How can I change the existing column length without dropping or hardcode existing database table.

`2020_02_13_065846_create_users_documents_table.php`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_documents', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('upload_url', 200)->nullable();
            $table->string('user_name', 50)->nullable();
        });
```

Now I want to change the length of column `user_name` to 200 by creating a new table.

Comment: You etheir correct it in that file and refresh the migration (deletes everything) or you make a new migration and add the alteration statement in it (production solution).

Comment: "_by creating new table_"? Why a new table?

Comment: You can change columns with [`change()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#modifying-columns) method.

Comment: i never used that solution @MohamedGamalEldin because it needs the package `doctrine/dbal` when you can do it with a statement.

Comment: I know that if small changes can use a statement but for big projects, I think `doctrine/dbal` is better. @N69S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to [modify](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#modifying-columns) you columns:

The change method allows you to modify the type and attributes of existing columns. For example, you may wish to increase the size of a string column

make a new Migration, set this statement:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('upload_url', 500)->change();
 $table->string('user_name', 500)->change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **Development solution**

you correct it in that file and refresh your migration with `php artisan migrate:fresh` but **you lose all the data** in your database

2. **Production solution**

Make a new migration with the alter statement.

```
public function up()
{
    \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE user_documents ALTER COLUMN upload_url VARCHAR (200)');
}
```